# How to load data during training of a multi-output model without iteration in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have a Keras model with 1 input and 2 outputs in TensorFlow 2. When calling `model.fit` I want to pass dataset as `x=train_dataset` and call `model.fit` once. The `train_dataset` is made with `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` which yields: x1, y1, y2.

The only way I can run training is the following:

```
for x1, y1,y2 in train_dataset:
    model.fit(x=x1, y=[y1,y2],...)
```

How to tell TensorFlow to unpack variables and train without the explicit `for` loop? Using the `for` loop makes many things less practical, as well as usage of `train_on_batch`.

If I want to run `model.fit(train_dataset, ...)` the function doesn't understand what `x` and `y` are, even the model is defined like:

```
model = Model(name ='Joined_Model',inputs=self.x, outputs=[self.network.y1, self.network.y2])
```

It throws an error that it is expecting 2 targets while getting 1, even the dataset has 3 variables, which can be iterated trough in the loop.

The dataset and mini-batch are generated as:

```
def dataset_joined(self, n_epochs, buffer_size=32):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        self.mbatch_gen_joined,
        (tf.float32, tf.float32,tf.int32),
        (tf.TensorShape([None, None, self.n_feat]),
            tf.TensorShape([None, None, self.n_feat]),
            tf.TensorShape([None, None])),
        [tf.constant(n_epochs)]
        )
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size)
    return dataset

    def mbatch_gen_joined(self, n_epochs):
    for _ in range(n_epochs):
        random.shuffle(self.train_s_list)
        start_idx, end_idx = 0, self.mbatch_size
        for _ in range(self.n_iter):
            s_mbatch_list = self.train_s_list[start_idx:end_idx]
            d_mbatch_list = random.sample(self.train_d_list, end_idx-start_idx)
            s_mbatch, d_mbatch, s_mbatch_len, d_mbatch_len, snr_mbatch, label_mbatch, _ = \
                self.wav_batch(s_mbatch_list, d_mbatch_list)
            x_STMS_mbatch, xi_bar_mbatch, _ = \
                self.training_example(s_mbatch, d_mbatch, s_mbatch_len,
                d_mbatch_len, snr_mbatch)
            #seq_mask_mbatch = tf.cast(tf.sequence_mask(n_frames_mbatch), tf.float32)
            start_idx += self.mbatch_size; end_idx += self.mbatch_size
            if end_idx > self.n_examples: end_idx = self.n_examples

            yield x_STMS_mbatch, xi_bar_mbatch, label_mbatch
```

Comment: Could you please add the code where you define and create the `Dataset` instance, along with the generator code?

Comment: What is y1 and y2? One hot encoded values?Can you please explain your target data. Also can you please share the code.

Comment: Hi, I have added the code in the question above @today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras models expect the Python generators or `tf.data.Dataset` objects provide the input data as a tuple with the format of `(input_data, target_data)` (or `(input_data, target_data, sample_weights)`). Each of `input_data` or `target_data` could and should be a list/tuple if the model has multiple input/output layers. Therefore, in your code, the generated data should also be compatible with this expected format:

```
yield x_STMS_mbatch, (xi_bar_mbatch, label_mbatch)  # <- the second element is a tuple itself
```

Also, this should be considered in the arguments passed to the `from_generator` method as well:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    self.mbatch_gen_joined,
    output_types=(
        tf.float32,
        (tf.float32, tf.int32)
    ),
    output_shapes=(
        tf.TensorShape([None, None, self.n_feat]),
        (
            tf.TensorShape([None, None, self.n_feat]),
            tf.TensorShape([None, None])
        )
    ),
    args=(tf.constant(n_epochs),)
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @today
I was close but couldn't make it without your help.

Could you possible have a look at this issue?


[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61441798/how-to-avoid-defining-target-tensors-in-tensorflow-2-ctc-loss-model)

Answer (score 0):

Use `yield(x1, [y1,y2])` so model.fit will understand your generator output.

Comment: Hi,
This is a good place to start, the generator should be changed accordingly. I tried to use the same structure in both generator and dataset, but it is refusing to generate.

`The two structures don't have the same sequence length. Input structure has length 3, while shallow structure has length 2.`

Comment: I have added the code above.
when yielding values as (x1, [y1,y2]) , the dataset generation should be changed. Just putting the values inside the brackets [] doesn't to do the job.

Comment: But the targets have different shapes, np.stack require all inputs to have the same dimension. 
I am not sure where and how you mean np.stack can help with the issue. @Augusto